# Volume Increases Just Before The Fade Out

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to fade audio as I change scenes, and the actual fade works fine. However, right when it starts the fade the audio get slightly louder making the whole thing sound bad. Im not sure why it is doing this so any help would be appreciated.

```
var gameMusic : AudioClip;
var gameVolume : float = 1.0;

function Start(){
    gameVolume = 1.0;
    audio.clip = gameMusic;
    audio.Play();
}
function Update(){

    if(SubMaster.gameOver){
        FadeOutSound();
        }
}

function FadeOutSound(){

    if(gameVolume > 0){
            gameVolume -= 0.1 * Time.deltaTime;
            audio.volume = gameVolume;
    }
}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have hardcoded gameVolume to 1.0 in Start.  Try setting it to the current audio.volume.

```
gameVolume = audio.volume;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting audio.volume to it's max value.

It's default is maybe .8

Then you change it to 1.0 before starting to decrease it.